# Question in proof of a lemma related to finding structure of finitely generated module in which every element is power of prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

While studying Abstract algebra from Thomas Hungerford I have a question in proof of Lemma 6.8 on page no. 222 in Unit -3.

It's image:[image]

> In last line of image, I am not able to determine how b lies in A and b$\neq$ 0 ?

I tried by using : c $\in$ A-Ra( given in first line ) but couldn't prove it .

Kindly help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$b\in A$ since it is the difference of two elements of $A$.  $b\ne0$ since otherwise $p^{j-1}c=rp^{k-1}a\in Ra$ contradicting minimality of $j$.